# AspectJ thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart does not compile

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm using a pointcut to log all exceptions in my aspect. Basically I'm doing this to log names of methods where exceptions were caught. To get the name of the method I've been using thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart and it used to work just fine until I migrated to Java 8 and AspectJ 1.8.0.

Now my old aspect won't compile anymore as I'm getting the following error: "The local variable thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart may not have been initialized".

Here's what my aspect looks like.

```
pointcut exceptionLogging(Exception e) : handler(Exception+) && args(e);

before(Exception e) : exceptionLogging(e) {
    String method = thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fails for me too. I think you are hitting a variant of https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431976 . That bug covered the `thisJoinPoint` case but I'll add a note about `thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart`. It is due to the new variable usage flow analysis in the Eclipse Java8 compiler, upon which AspectJ is now based.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works nicely, e.g.

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            throw new Exception("my exception");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public aspect MyAspect {
    pointcut exceptionLogging(Exception e) : handler(Exception+) && args(e);

    before(Exception e) : exceptionLogging(e) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart + " -> " + e);
        System.out.println(thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart);
        System.out.println(thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
handler(catch(Exception)) -> java.lang.Exception: my exception
execution(void Application.main(String[]))
main
java.lang.Exception: my exception
    at Application.main(Application.java:4)
```

Comment: Which version of Java/AspectJ are you using? I had no trouble with the code prior to migrating From Java 7 to Java 8(which required me to upgrade my eclipse and AJDT).

Comment: I am not at home now, but looked this up quickly via remote access. I use a combination of Java 7 and AspectJ 1.8.0. I also quickly tested with Java 8. It works with language level 7, but fails with language level 8, i.e. I can reproduce the problem now. Sorry for having missed the Java 8 part of your question, my bad.